# How to find rows length in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am trying to get rows length on datatable loading time. But it's not getting the length.

```
$("button#searchbutton").click(function() {
                          var txnid = $("#transactionid").val();
                          var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                              "ajax" : "/doTxnSearchList?txnid="+txnid,
                              "bDestroy":true,
                                "columns":[
                                    {"data": "txnid" },
                                    {"data": "fromDate"},                                        
                                    {"data": "amount"},                                        
                                    {"data": "mobileno"}
                                   ],
                                   "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                                           "language": {
                                               "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                                               "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                                               "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                                               "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                                           },

                                           "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                                          "lengthChange": false,
                                       //   "sScrollY": "250px",
                                          "bAutoWidth": false,
                                         // "bScrollCollapse": true,
                                          "fnInitComplete": function() {
                                            this.css("visibility", "visible");
                                          },
                          });                           
                          alert(oTable.fnGetData(this).length);
                      });
```

I am trying to get length in alert `alert(oTable.fnGetData(this).length);` after table loading.

Anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) api for finding the data length from ajax call

In your code

```
$("button#searchbutton").click(function() {
                      var txnid = $("#transactionid").val();
                      var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                          "ajax" : "/doTxnSearchList?txnid="+txnid,
                          "bDestroy":true,
                            "columns":[
                                {"data": "txnid" },
                                {"data": "fromDate"},                                        
                                {"data": "amount"},                                        
                                {"data": "mobileno"}
                               ],
                               "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                                       "language": {
                                           "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                                           "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                                           "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                                           "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                                       },

                                       "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                                      "lengthChange": false,
                                   //   "sScrollY": "250px",
                                      "bAutoWidth": false,
                                     // "bScrollCollapse": true,
                                      "fnInitComplete": function() {
                                        this.css("visibility", "visible");
                                      },
                                      "initComplete":function(settings,json)
                                       {
                                        console.log(json.length);
                                       }

                      });                           
                   });
```

Comment: what is jquery version?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  You're trying to access the 1.10 API with the older API methods. fnGetData has been deprecated, as you're seeing.

Here are the details about the API : https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

**Solution** : `oTable.rows().count()` you have use this API.

```
alert(oTable.fnGetData(this).length); //replace this code with the following code 

alert(oTable.rows().count());  //it will number rows into your datatable
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/xwjga044/175/

Reference :  https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()

Hope this will help  you.

Comment: i am getting `oTable.rows(...).count is not a function` error on console.

Comment: oTable is your table Id

Comment: no it is variable. `var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({});`

Comment: is there any method replace of `count()`?

Comment: have you check the js fiddle working demo example. http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/xwjga044/175/

Comment: What is the jquery plugin version?

Comment: in your fiddle demo is working but in my logic it is throwing error.